# ANTLR3 - Recognise keywords in any text with spaces

Tags: keyword, antlr4

Is it possible to define a grammar in ANTLR4 that would recognise keywords in a text with spaces allowed, such as:

```
First goal refinedInto Goal two, Goal three
Another goal refinedInto ...
```

Here "refinedInto" is a keyword. So far, I have come up with the following parser and lexer, but don't think it's the right way of going about my problem. Namely because my REF_LEFT token evaluates for my example above to "First goal refinedInto" and I would like to separate "First goal" from the "refinedInto" keyword.

Here's my parser:

```
parser grammar GParse;

parse
    : REF_LEFT ( STRING COMMA )* STRING EOF
    ;
```

and here the lexer:

```
lexer grammar GLex;

REF_LEFT: [a-zA-Z ]+? 'refinedInto ' -> pushMode(RDef);

mode RDef;

STRING : [a-zA-Z ]+;
COMMA  : ',' ' '*;
NL     : ('\n' | EOF) -> popMode;
```

What is the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several different approaches you could take.  The most direct is to just let the lexer rule consume the possible spaces as part of the literal text of the keyword. Adjust to include tabs and new lines if needed.

```
RDef_To : 'redefinedInto'
        | 'redefined' SPACES 'Into'
        ;

Ws: ( SPACES | TABS ) -> channel(HIDDEN) ;  // should work with 'skip' too
Term: NLINES ; // if used as the record terminator.

fragment NLINES: ( '\r'? '\n' )+ | '\f'+ ;
fragment SPACES: ' '+ ;
fragment TABS:   '\t'+ ;
```

Comment: The thing is I want to preserve spaces. In a text such as "First goal refinedInto Second goal, ..." I need to recognise the text "First goal" and trigger an action that will save that into an object. If I consume spaces my goal names (First goal) won't be preserved. Goal names can be any sequence of characters including spaces, except for the keyword "refinedInto".

Comment: @David Did you define "refinedInto" as an own Lexer token (e.g. `REFINED : 'refinedInto'` and use this in your `REF_LEFT: [a-zA-Z ]+? REFINED -> pushMode(RDef);`? Then at least you should be able to identify this token in the parse result.